# How to use FastMM on XE7 C++ Builder for FireMonkey projects?

Tags: delphi, memory-leaks, c++builder, firemonkey, fastmm

I'm trying to use FastMM full debug mode in XE7 C++ builder, particularly for FireMonkey. I downloaded the source code and followed the steps outline in 'FastMM4BCB.cpp'.  In order to get FastMM compile, I made following changes:

1. comment out Line 63 in 'FastMM4BCB.cpp', which is:
   *#pragma option -k- -d -vi- -O2 -b- -3 -a8 -pc -RT- -x -xd -r -AT -vG- -vG0- -vG1- -vG2- -vG3- -vGc- -vGt- -vGd-*
2. in my project file, add a line:  *#pragma link "FastMM4BCB"* 
   instead of (as described in 'FastMM4BCB.cpp') *USEOBJ("FastMM4BCB.cpp")*

With these changes, FastMM compiles and runs successfully. However, it reports memory leaks on even blank projects (I tried both FireMonkey and VCL) as follows:

1. 13-20 bytes: Unknown x 8
2. 61-68 bytes: Unknown x 1
3. 189 - 204 bytes: Unknown x 1

With VCL projects, I was able to use full debug mode and get some details about these memory leaks (for example):

```
--------------------------------2014/10/23 16:58:26--------------------------------
A memory block has been leaked. The size is: 20

This block was allocated by thread 0x628, and the stack trace (return addresses) at the time was:
41C897 
41C591 
415A2D 
40E4B1 
40E4BB 
40EE45 
76F73C5A [Unknown function at RtlImageNtHeader]
76FCB19C [Unknown function at RtlUlonglongByteSwap]
76F957CE [RtlLoadString]
76F73CD3 [Unknown function at RtlImageNtHeader]
76F73CD3 [Unknown function at RtlImageNtHeader]

The block is currently used for an object of class: Unknown

The allocation number is: 12

Current memory dump of 256 bytes starting at pointer address 7EF1A160:
80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 E0 9B F3 7E 80 80 80 80 C3 7E 6A 2C 80 80 80 80 00 00 00 00 80 9F F1 7E
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 A8 7A 40 00 00 00 00 00 15 00 00 00 97 C8 41 00 91 C5 41 00 2D 5A 41 00
23 B1 40 00 B1 E4 40 00 BB E4 40 00 6C 60 42 00 F7 F1 40 00 5A 3C F7 76 9C B1 FC 76 CE 57 F9 76
28 06 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 80 1D 2A E6
80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 E0 9B F3 7E 80 80 80 80 7F E2 D5 19 80 80 80 80 00 00 00 00 21 AC F1 7E
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 16 00 00 00 97 C8 41 00 91 C5 41 00 2D 5A 41 00
6C 60 42 00 4A F6 40 00 5A 3C F7 76 9C B1 FC 76 CE 57 F9 76 D3 3C F7 76 D3 3C F7 76 FE 3C F7 76
â‚¬  â‚¬  â‚¬  â‚¬  â‚¬  â‚¬  â‚¬  â‚¬  Ã   â€º  Ã³  ~  â‚¬  â‚¬  â‚¬  â‚¬  Ãƒ  ~  j  ,  â‚¬  â‚¬  â‚¬  â‚¬  .  .  .  .  â‚¬  Å¸  Ã±  ~
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  Â¨  z  @  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  â€”  Ãˆ  A  .  â€˜  Ã…  A  .  -  Z  A  .
#  Â±  @  .  Â±  Ã¤  @  .  Â»  Ã¤  @  .  l  `  B  .  Ã·  Ã±  @  .  Z  <  Ã·  v  Å“  Â±  Ã¼  v  ÃŽ  W  Ã¹  v
(  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  â‚¬  .  *  Ã¦
â‚¬  â‚¬  â‚¬  â‚¬  â‚¬  â‚¬  â‚¬  â‚¬  Ã   â€º  Ã³  ~  â‚¬  â‚¬  â‚¬  â‚¬    Ã¢  Ã•  .  â‚¬  â‚¬  â‚¬  â‚¬  .  .  .  .  !  Â¬  Ã±  ~
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  â€”  Ãˆ  A  .  â€˜  Ã…  A  .  -  Z  A  .
l  `  B  .  J  Ã¶  @  .  Z  <  Ã·  v  Å“  Â±  Ã¼  v  ÃŽ  W  Ã¹  v  Ã“  <  Ã·  v  Ã“  <  Ã·  v  Ã¾  <  Ã·
```

With a blank FireMonkey projects, it raises (in full debug mode) an access violation error when app closes at the address 0x80 pattern as marked by FastMM.  Any idea how to make it work for FireMonkey an remove these false positive alerts on blank projects?  Thanks

Comment: I would suggest contacting Pierre lqe Riche and ask how to use FastMM with FireMonkey. As for the leaks, either they are real bugs leaking memory, or Embarcadero simply forgot to register them as expected leaks.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I'm also a bit concerned about the changes I made to the source code. I'm not familiar with the source at all and those changes were simply made to get it compiled.  Do you think those changes would cause unexpected behavior?

Comment: you should not have messed with the source code. It is passing a lot of parameters to the compiler on purpose. If you have a compiler error, file a bug report with Pierre.

Comment: any updates? I also want to use FastMM on C++ builder 2010.